# Nodemanager in unhealthy state

Tags: hadoop

I am working on hadoop-2.6.0 single node cluster in windows. When i submit any mapreduce job, it always in accepted state. It seems my nodemanager is in unhealthy state. How to make it healthy? Why the nodemanager in unhealthy state? or when it will back to the healthy state?

Comment: have a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29010039/yarn-unhealthy-nodes/29061409#29061409

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution [here](http://newscentral.exsees.com/item/b29d079dbdb7e357348a5d4c3926955f-ea6fac97fddcf012711bbc83f8372aed)

It seems that the cause of the problem is low disk space in the hadoop installed drive. So i just cleaned up with more space then nodemanager automatically changed into healthy state. We can't do it manually using any commands for changing the states of the hadoop nodes as analyzed.

Answer (score 0):

When the job is in Accepted stage , it means that its waiting for the datanode to accept and start processing.

The following are to be done:

1. Check for available slots
2. If slots are available and its taking time to change status to Running , then check the datanodes health using either cloudera manager or hadoop dfs admin command.

If there are dead nodes , Restarting would solve the issue.

Comment: If the nodemanager available in the healthy state then only job can be submit. But in my case nodemanager is in unhealthy state, so the job is not assigned yet (accepted state). I want to know how to make the nodemanager back to healthy state. Is there any command to do that. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Never format namenode, that will make landscape inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add the config in `yarn-site.xml`

```
name=yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.enable value=false
```